# Jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Need a little help with my jquery here

I want all my button  with a name starting with "my-" and finishing with "-press" to have a "click" event.

```
<input type="button" id="my-button-x-press" name="my-button-x-name-press" />
```

Buttons dynamically added to DOM should have the same event.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$('input[type=button][name^=my-][name$=-press]').click(function() {
   // code
})
```

To assign event to elements dynamically, use `on` http://api.jquery.com/on/ and supply your selector as the second argument to properly `delegate` event.

```
$('#container').on('click', 'input[type=button][name^=my-][name$=-press]', function() {
   // code
})
```

Assuming you are wrapping your inputs on `#container`, otherwise replace `#container` with `body`, but it's always preferable to select the closest ancestor of the `selector`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), and the [attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), and the [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method to catch events for elements that are added later on:

```
$('body').delegate('input[type=button][name^="my-"][name$="-press"]', 'click', function(){
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

give them all a class and do:

```
$('.classname').click(function(){etc.});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
$('#my-'+dunamic_change_here+'-press').click(function(){
  // your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

```
$('input[name^="my-"]input[name$="-press"]').click(function(){
    //Stuff to happen.
});
```

If they are dynamically added to the dom:

```
$('input[name^="my-"]input[name$="-press"]').on('click', function(){
    //Stuff to happen.
});
```

Matpols answer is probably the simplest way to do it actually.

Comment: If the inputs are dynamically inserted then the `on()` would have to be bound to an ancestor element, not the element that's dynamically inserted.